# How to call a method within a programmatically generated fragment from the parent activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**EDIT 4** Alright, so I've changed my example code to exactly what was suggested, with a null check.

now in the public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity I've got

```
private templateFragment1 fragTest;
```

and then in onCreate I've got

```
 final FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
    fragTest = (templateFragment1) fragMan.findFragmentByTag("1");

    onSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            if(fragTest != null) {
                String editTestText = fragTest.editTextGetter();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editTestText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And in templateFragment1 I've got

```
privateEditText text;
```

which I've binded in onCreateView like this

```
text = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextTest);
```

then I have the method underneath onCreateView

```
public String editTextGetter(){
    String value1 = text.getText().toString();
    return value1;
   }
```

And now what happens..is nothing. I hit the save button and there's no Toast, no error message. So I guess this means it's returning null?

**EDIT 3** Here's a couple videos demonstrating the bug.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w60Vljd2R4M&feature=youtu.be

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqpVGBAHw0w&feature=youtu.be

I understand that there are several questions similar to this already, but none seem to address my specific issue here.

Inside my main activity I have a button that adds instances of fragments. Each time it does it also assigns them a tag of "1", "2", etc. Just to see if it's possible, I'm only trying to call a method from the first one.

In my main activity I have:

```
    // initializing button that will call the fragment's method
    Button onSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);


    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();

    // calling my first created fragment
    final templateFragment1 fragTest = (templateFragment1) fragMan.findFragmentByTag("1");


    // my button that should call the frag's method and then display it as a toast
    onSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            // here I'm assigning the fragment's method to a string
            String editTestText = fragTest.editTextGetter();

            // display as toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editTestText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

In my fragment:

```
public String editTextGetter(){
    EditText text = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextTest);
    String value1 = text.getText().toString();
    return value1;
}
```

editTextGetter() is below the onCreateView method if that matters.

Now what happens is just an app crash upon clicking the main activity's button.

**EDIT**: Here's my commit code as requested:

```
addDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            ++fragIdCount;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            String fragString = Integer.toString(fragIdCount);
            templateFragment1 frag2 = new templateFragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.templateFragmentLayout, frag2, fragString);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

As you can see, I'm incrementing a number from 0 (fragIdCount) and then converting it to a string. I then assign that as the tag of the fragment. So I'm trying to call my fragments with this assigned tag.

**EDIT 2:** OK guys, here's code that can copy+pasted into a new project. It replicates my issues, and I'd really appreciate if yall could take a look at it!

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int fragIdCount = 0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button addDay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDay);
    Button removeDay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeDay);

// Here I'm making it so I have an instance of the fragment displayed on create
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    String fragString = Integer.toString(fragIdCount);
    templateFragment1 frag2 = new templateFragment1();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.templateFragmentLayout, frag2, fragString);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


// My button that adds fragment. Obviously this can quickly generate a bunch of fragment instances
// I try to make that manageable by incrementing a fragment count to use as tags
    addDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            ++fragIdCount;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            String fragString = Integer.toString(fragIdCount);
            templateFragment1 frag2 = new templateFragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.templateFragmentLayout, frag2,    fragString);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

        }
    });

// remove button. same concept as the add button
    removeDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            String fragString = Integer.toString(fragIdCount);
            //Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragString);
            if(fragIdCount != 0){
                fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragString)).commit();
                --fragIdCount;
            }
        }
    });

// initialize Save button (which SHOULD get the value of an editText from whichever
// fragment I specify)
    Button onSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

    onSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            // Eventually I'll want to make this a for loop to perform this operation on all fragments created.
            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();

            // this should get the fragment "1"
            templateFragment1 fragTest = (templateFragment1)   fragMan.findFragmentByTag("1");
            // and this should run the method "editTextGetter()" inside of  the previously specified fragment
            String editTestText = fragTest.editTextGetter();

            // just a quick way to show if I got the correct value, for debugging
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editTestText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              tools:context="com.liftrpoc.scheduler1.pushpulldetails"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/templateFragmentLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addDay"
            android:text="Add Day"
    />

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/removeDay"
            android:text="Remove Day"
    />


    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:text="Save"
    />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

templateFragment1.java

```
public class templateFragment1 extends Fragment {
public templateFragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_template_fragment1, container, false);

    // a good bit of extra code that adds it's own instanced fragments, just like in the main activity.
    // this shouldn't have anything to do with what we're trying to do  though. It doesn't touch anything else.

    return view;
}

// here's the editText method I'm trying to access from my main activity.
public String editTextGetter(){
    EditText text = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextTest);
    String value1 = text.getText().toString();
    return value1;
}

}
```

fragment_template_fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#E3E3E3"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/ParentLinearLayout1"
>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTest"
/>

</LinearLay
```

Comment: A stacktrace would be helpful.  It's likely a null pointer exception. Did you double-check that fragTest isn't null after `final templateFragment1 fragTest = (templateFragment1) fragMan.findFragmentByTag("1");` ?

Comment: can you post log and fragment commit() code ?

Comment: post your logcat plz

Comment: @JesseBuss how would I go about checking if fragTest is null or not? 
I'll get the logcat and commit() code up as soon as I get back home to my computer, thanks guys.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya here's my commit code

Comment: @JesseBuss I implemented a null checker in my Edit 4 of my original post. I believe it is indeed returning null. What would be my options now? I also added code that can be copy/pasted and run, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList and store each fragment you make in it.
then when you want to call an specific function in your fragment or get a view just get your desired fragment from the ArrayList and after that do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Some areas of improvement to your code:

- In your main activity, it's easier to just make `fragTest` a class property.

```
private templateFragment1 fragTest;

/** I believe these exists in your onCreate()? **/

    // initializing button that will call the fragment's method
    Button onSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();

    // calling my first created fragment
    fragTest = (templateFragment1) fragMan.findFragmentByTag("1");
    if(fragTest == null) {
        // Create fragTest
    }

    // my button that should call the frag's method and then display it as a toast
    onSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            // Wrapping this with a null pointer check may be unnecessary
            // but callbacks can be ... funny.
            if(fragTest != null {
                // here I'm assigning the fragment's method to a string
                String editTestText = fragTest.editTextGetter();

                // display as toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editTestText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

/** End of onCreate **/
```

- In your fragment, again, make `text` a class property and bind to it's view in `onCreateView`.

```
private EditText text;

// TODO In onCreateView, bind text to R.id.editTextTest

    public String editTextGetter(){
        String value1 = text.getText().toString();
        return value1;
    }
```

**Other considerations**

- Orientation changes: you may want to add `setRetainInstance(true)` to the `onCreate` of you fragments. Full details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the suggestions! I was losing hope anyone would answer haha. So, I made these changes and I'm still having the problems. Could you take a look at my edit? I'm going to post full code that can be copy-pasted and compiled to help better show the problem. I'll also upload a quick Youtube video showing the bug in action. Thanks again, this bug is absolutely killing my schedule right now.

Comment: From you edit, I still don't see a null check for fragment with tag "1" in your  `Button onSave` listener. I think you should review if you're actually retrieving the correct fragment tag, as from what I've seen in your code, the only "guaranteed" fragment will be with tag "0".

Comment: @Ade.Akenyede Alright, I've got the null check now, it's in EDIT 4 of my original post. Now when I've got the null checker, nothing happens. I guess this means that I'm return null on the fragment tag finder? Would this mean my tag assignment is working?

Comment: You can debug and put a breakpoint at that point in the code. Essentially there will be no fragment with tag "1" i.e. `fragtest`, if the `addDay` button hasn't been pressed at least once (of course pressing `removeDay` can eventually remove it). Just to highlight, `fragIdCount` **starts** from **0**.

Comment: When I set findFragmentByTag("0") it doesn't get the auto-generated fragment. The auto-generated fragment should have tag 0 because fragIdCount starts at 0. And when I'm looking for fragment "1" I'm making sure I add a fragment before checking with the save button. Do you think you could try my code? Just to see if the error is the same?